# Event Hub - Invalid Token error Azure Stream Analytics Input

Tags: azure

I am trying to to follow the tutorial below

[Azure Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-real-time-fraud-detection)

As noted at the bottom there appear to have been changes since this was created

When I get to the part where I create an input for my stream analytics job, I cannot select an event hub even though there is one in my subscription

So I went to provide the information manually and I get an error stating invalid token

Has anyone got any ideas how to resolve this or can point me to a better/more recent tutorial?

I am looking to stream data in real time

Paul

Comment: Where are you getting the token from? Is it based off of one of the configured policies for your event hub? I recently went through the same exercise and had to manually configure the stream input and it worked out just fine for me

Comment: Yes it's from the configured policy I took the primary key from it

Comment: Querying EventHub returned an error: Management operation failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help here I ended up using the secondary key and that worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Change to use Secondary connection string or use a different shared policy altogether.
You can use the primary of the new shared access policy.
PS : It is a weird error, sometimes removing the last ";" worked.